# SVN Server not asking for credentials

Tags: svn

I have Collabnet Subversion Server 1.8.9 running.

In svnserve.conf I have set:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

In the passwd file I have set up users and passwords.

```
user1 = blah1
user2 - blah2
```

However, when I view the repository using Tortoise SVN Repository Browser and the URL http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/svn/myrepo it doesn't prompt for any credentials.

Developers have been using it to store code, but when I look at the files in Tortoise, the author column is blank. So it looks like it's letting them use it without checking their credentials.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`svnserve.conf` is the convention used to reference the configuration file used by `svnserve` and the `svn://` protocol. You are using Apache to serve your repository via HTTP. Unless your `http.conf` is referencing this file (which is unlikely, because there's some slightly different syntax at the top), you've done nothing to configure the access controls you want.

Read the [httpd, the Apache HTTP Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) section of the Subversion manual to see how to properly set up authentication & authorization with this server option.